# Have a separate URL for every language in laravel using one template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

last time I created the multilingual templates that have one route and one `URL`, and I would change the languages through `SESSION` without changing the `URL` or change its folder. But later I realized that Google only indexed one language. Which was the default language of the website? This is a problem. Now I want to use `URL` separately for each language. But I do not want to use two templates. I have an idea, like changing the controllers of any language or the routes of any language, but I do not know, is it executive?

- If you have a better solution please tell?
- Is my strategy executive or not? How is it?
- Is there anyway, Google can handle all language without changing `URL`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***I find a solution that was helpful***

Install the package via composer: `composer require mcamara/laravel-localization`

for more details see this link.

https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Answer (score 2):

Then you have to add the language to your route/url and set your locale first.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

In the documentation it's well explained.

```
Route::get('welcome/{locale}', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
});
```

Comment: do you have any other idea?

Comment: Hmm that is difficult. You could define language URLs for Google and make a sitemap where they are included. So have your main URL without language but all other with the locale parameter.